# How to know a .jar nexus artifact issued from which branch

Tags: java, maven, jar, ansible, nexus

I want to know from which branch an artifact is generated since we have the same version in pom.xml file

how can I differentiate between two SNAPSHOTS jars generated from from two branches.

Comment: nexus doesn't hold that information. probably you have to cross check creation times with the build times from your build pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Nexus is an artifact controller and holder. It stores only the artifacts without considering from where the artifact has come. One can manually upload the artifact in Nexus. To your question, there is no way to track the branch details from Nexus .jar files. However, if you have any Continuous Integration server like Jenkins, it may provide the details which branch uploaded the jar file to Nexus.

Comment: Read these links. https://medium.com/@kasunbg/maven-git-nexus-jenkins-automate-maven-releases-with-jenkins-65fbad0023d0